# Jquery div selection

Tags: jquery

I want to show/hide div(s) using following code. But when I implement it does not work for me. Please help me in this regard. Thank you.

http://jsfiddle.net/fysalyaqoob/6fornysr/1/

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.post').hide()
    $('.' + this.id).show(500);
});

$('#showall').click(function() {
    $('.post').show(500);
});
```

it is not working with html code:

```
<div class="1">
    <div class="2">
        <div class="wedding post">WEDDING DIL</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You dont have a `button` HTML element.. neither do you have a node with id `showall` in the code you have shown. Can you create a fiddle reproducing your issue ??

Comment: Do you have any <button> elements? Are they siblings to (".post")? Please post your full HTML.

Comment: What does "does not want for me" mean?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fysalyaqoob/6fornysr/1/ link for full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`siblings` selects all direct child nodes sharing the same parent. If you want to find nested nodes you can use `$(this).parent().find('.post').hide()`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6fornysr/5/).

or even `$('.post')` if want to find all posts within the document.

Comment: brilliant. exactly need this.

Answer (score 0):

On your 2nd line of script you are using

```
$(this).siblings('.post').hide()
```

Which means, when clicked on `button`s you are only hiding the **siblings** which are having the `.post` class. Since the first div with `.wedding.post` class is not a sibling of `button`s it's not hiding when clicked.

You need to remove the parent divs of first `.wedding.post` div in order to work perfectly.

**Example -**

```
<div class="wedding post">WEDDING DIL</div>
<div class="portrait post">PORTRAIT 1</div>
<div class="personal post">PERSONAL 1</div>
<div class="wedding post">WEDDING 2</div>
<div class="wedding post">WEDDING 3</div>
<div class="portrait post">PORTRAIT 2</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/6fornysr/4/)** here